# useEffect not working in custom drawer component without refresh

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

So I am using react-navigation 5 and I have a custom drawer component for my app. I want to display the name of the logged-in user in the drawer for which I am using a state variable and I am updating the state from firestore. I am calling a function in useEffect which accesses firestore and gets the name of the user. But I think the useEffect is not working without refresh because unless I save the project and refresh the application the state is not getting updated in the application and I cannot see the name of the user without refreshing but it is visible after a refresh. Any ideas why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Custom drawer

```
export default function CustomDrawer(props) {

    const paperTheme = useTheme();

    const [name,setName]=useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
            doStuff();
      }, []);
      const doStuff = async () => {
        var phone=global.phone;
        await firestore().collection("Users").where('Phone Number', '==', phone).get().then(querySnapshot=>{
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                console.log("in drawer");
                console.log(documentSnapshot.data());
                setName(documentSnapshot.data().Name);               
            })           
        })
      };

    return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <View style={styles.drawerContent}>
                    <View style={styles.userInfoSection}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginTop: 15}}>
                            <Avatar.Image 
                                source={{
                                    uri: ''
                                }}
                                size={50}
                            />
                            <View style={{marginLeft:15, flexDirection:'column'}}>
                                <Title style={styles.title}>{name}</Title>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have `doStuff` function defined outside the `useEffects`.

Either you need to put it inside `useEffects` or add it in dependency list

```
useEffect(() => {
    doStuff();
  }, [doStuff]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately doing it this way stopped the working completely

Comment: Is it? sorry for that. Did you try placing `doStuff` inside useEffect as well? can you give code sand box sample code.?

Comment: Here is concepts where functions are passed as dependeny to useEffect -> https://www.benmvp.com/blog/helper-functions-react-useeffect-hook/

Comment: yea I understand that but the issue is useeffect is not running only when the application I s initially rendered. It only runs when I save my drawer component and the application refreshes, which I don't understand why is happening. 63

Comment: Ok, I realized my mistake. The drawer component is mounted at the login phase itself, and at that phase, the component doesn't have a user id for identifying the username to display in the component, so I simply added the userid in the dependency of the use effect and when the userid changes the useeffect runs again and it started working. Thanks for your help.